# what is the value for setting a hostname in installation of oracle enterprise linux r6u5 should have?

Tags: virtual-machine, hostname

I am installing oracle linux r6u5 for my personal use in vmware workstation. While going through installatio i came to a point where I have to enter hostname, format specified init is "localhost.localdomain". What value should I give there? should that be a live domain name over internet or it can be any in the format specified in it "localhost.localdomain" or IP address of host OS(Windows 8 where VmWare is installed on).

Please help me with this I am installing Linux for first time.

Answer (score 1):

For hostname you can use any computer/host/server name you like, like "mypc". For example the contents of my `/etc/hosts` are:

```
# /etc/hosts: static lookup table for host names
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>       <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain       localhost
127.0.0.1       jurassicpark.localdomain    jurassicpark
::1             localhost.localdomain       localhost
```

and of my `/etc/hostname`:

```
jurassicpark
```

Hence my system is named "jurassicpark" and every time I enter the console I get

```
[pidosaurus@jurassicpark ~]$
```

There is also some Oracle documentation [here](http://www.oracledistilled.com/linux/changing-the-hostname-on-oracle-enterprise-linux/).

I do not understand what do you mean with "format specified init" (?).

Welcome to the Linux world. I assume you install "Oracle linux" because of corporate (or similar?) needs. If not and you want to try other distributions, you can check them at [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/).